# Change ajax returned status code

Tags: c#, jquery, httpresponse

I have the following web metod:

```
[WebMethod]

    public static string SayHello()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserData"] != null)
        {
                  //do something
        }

        else
        {
            response.StatusCode = 401;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            throw new HttpException(401, "timeout");
        }
    }
```

and this is the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/SayHello',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{ }',
    success: function(Result) {


        //do something
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             xhr.StatusCode = 500
    }
});
```

I always get 500 (Internal Server Error) status code in $.ajax error var xhr.StatusCode
Can I change it inside the WebMethod?

I want to change it to 401 (Unauthorized) and inside $.ajaxError redirect to the login page..

Comment: 500 indicates something is actually wrong with the webservice call. Returning other response codes is normally straight-forward. Try calling your webservice using something like Fiddler2 to post to it and see what you get back.

Comment: I get 500 because I throw an exception... If I remove it I get 200, but I want to know that the session is not exist anymore

Comment: Then you're throwing something incorrectly.  When you debug it where does it break?

Comment: just return a JSON with the value you want if the session is valid and an error message when it's not. Don't throw exceptions for every error you might have, it's not a good practice.